# Multiple values with same tag

Tags: javascript, json, api

Okay, so I have the following code, which is supposed to search Urban Dictionary for a certain term and then log the definition to the console:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?term=polar%20vortex", true);
xhr.onload = function (e) {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
      var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      console.log("Definition: " + response.list.definition);
    } else {
      console.error(xhr.statusText);
    }
  }
};
xhr.onerror = function (e) {
  console.error(xhr.statusText);
};
xhr.send(null);
```

However, when I run the code, it returns a value of "undefined".  I believe that this is because there are multiple "definition" tags under the "list" tag in the JSON (take a look [here](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/?jsondata=&jsondataurl=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.urbandictionary.com%2Fv0%2Fdefine%3Fterm%3Dpolar%2520vortex&template=0&validate=on)).

So, my question is, how can I get the first definition and ignore all of the other values with the "definition" tag?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not able to see the JSON from your provided link, can you post an example of what is being returned? Also, lol @ what you're pulling.

Comment: `this is because there are multiple "definition"` No. It does not matter if you have multiple keys then you should be getting the value of the last one. But most possibly `list` is an array or it is not what you think it is. Show us the JSON..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `response.list` is an array. So you can simply access it by index:

```
console.log("Definition: " + response.list[0].definition);
```

That should give you the first definition in the list.